Invert text on navbar depending on background color in HTML
How can I invert the text on my navbar when the color of an element below it is the same color? I tried using the filter function in css, but that seems to just permanently invert the color. I have also went onto a few other SO osts but they dont seem to work.
Here is a code snippet:


/** @format */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #000000;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #5c5b5b;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: background-color 0.15s linear;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
    cursor: grab;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
    cursor: grabbing;
}

.main-hero {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

body {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #eeeeee !important;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    background: #1a1a1a !important;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.navbar {
    margin: 10px;
}

.navbar .nav-link {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    transition: color 0.15 ease-in-out;
}

.navbar .nav-link:hover {
    color: blue;
}

.navbar .nav-link::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 0;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: blue;
    transition: width 0.15s ease;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.navbar .nav-link:hover::before {
    width: 100%;
}

.rules-btn {
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid blue !important;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 5px !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 70px;
    transition: border-color linear 0.15s, color linear 0.15s;
}

.rules-btn:hover {
    border-color: red !important;
    color: red;
}

/*main section*/

.main-heading {
    font-size: 90px;
}
<!-- @format -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="h-100">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="description" content="The official website for Cratex SMP" />
        <meta name="author" content="Cratex SMP" />
        <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.122.0" />
        <title>Cratex SMP</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH"
            crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <script
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body class="h-100 text-center">
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark fixed-top mb-auto">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <a class="navbar-brand nav-link" href="index.html">Cratex SMP</a>
                    <button
                        class="navbar-toggler"
                        type="button"
                        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                        data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse"
                        aria-controls="navbarCollapse"
                        aria-expanded="false"
                        aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarCollapse">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="active mx-1 py-1 nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="mx-1 py-1 nav-link" href="#">Support</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="mx-1 py-1 nav-link" href="https://store.cratexsmp.com">Store</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a
                                    style="mix-blend-mode: difference"
                                    class="text-decoration-none mx-1 py-1 d-inline-block rules-btn"
                                    href="rules.html"
                                    >Rules</a
                                >
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, nam aspernatur delectus optio quos eveniet
            repudiandae culpa quo esse corporis similique accusamus cum nobis officia totam doloremque? Laudantium, corporis
            dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis illo, ea possimus, aspernatur est,
            impedit natus dolores ipsam eveniet autem maxime sit accusamus doloremque quo veritatis corporis nemo totam
            
            similique error animi deleniti porro modi aut iste necessitatibus tempore et eligendi dolorum, esse omnis sequi
            veritatis quas maxime officiis incidunt. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, nam
            aspernatur delectus optio quos eveniet repudiandae culpa quo esse corporis similique accusamus cum nobis officia
            totam doloremque? Laudantium, corporis dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis
            illo, ea possimus, aspernatur est, impedit natus dolores ipsam eveniet autem maxime sit accusamus doloremque quo
            veritatis corporis nemo totam cupiditate! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus
            natus dolor inventore nulla voluptate sunt eaque, vero odit perferendis. Dolores eius soluta maxime, perferendis
            provident sit obcaecati asperiores quasi inventore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Corporis aliquam, omnis fugiat exercitationem vitae accusantium, aspernatur earum quam blanditiis tempore a
            delectus sunt id ullam praesentium, natus eveniet soluta mollitia. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
            adipisicing elit. Ratione, veniam libero qui deleniti blanditiis repudiandae autem. Inventore nobis, nemo
            accusamus sit, cum, praesentium perspiciatis excepturi animi earum voluptatum ab laudantium? Lorem ipsum, dolor
            sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium libero sunt nihil corrupti quisquam a illum labore similique
            soluta quia voluptatem repellat necessitatibus autem ut quos harum accusamus, earum repudiandae. Lorem ipsum,
            dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sunt veniam sed optio cum sequi, id error quis ab aliquam
            non iste molestiae obcaecati maxime fugiat ut eius incidunt? Veniam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
            adipisicing elit. Voluptas possimus ex consectetur ipsam alias, aperiam labore doloremque placeat perferendis
            quisquam numquam at earum dolorem deleniti libero! Magni non explicabo aspernatur! Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet
            consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto similique error animi deleniti porro modi aut iste necessitatibus tempore et
            eligendi dolorum, esse omnis sequi veritatis quas maxime officiis incidunt. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet
            consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, nam aspernatur delectus optio quos eveniet repudiandae culpa quo esse
            corporis similique accusamus cum nobis officia totam doloremque? Laudantium, corporis dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor,
            sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis illo, ea possimus, aspernatur est, impedit natus dolores ipsam
            eveniet autem maxime sit accusamus doloremque quo veritatis corporis nemo totam cupiditate! Lorem ipsum dolor sit
            amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus natus dolor inventore nulla voluptate sunt eaque, vero odit
            perferendis. Dolores eius soluta maxime, perferendis provident sit obcaecati asperiores quasi inventore. Lorem
            ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis aliquam, omnis fugiat exercitationem vitae
            accusantium, aspernatur earum quam blanditiis tempore a delectus sunt id ullam praesentium, natus eveniet soluta
            mollitia. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, veniam libero qui deleniti blanditiis
            repudiandae autem. Inventore nobis, nemo accusamus sit, cum, praesentium perspiciatis excepturi animi earum
            voluptatum ab laudantium? Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium libero sunt nihil
            corrupti quisquam a illum labore similique soluta quia voluptatem repellat necessitatibus autem ut quos harum
            accusamus, earum repudiandae. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sunt veniam sed
            optio cum sequi, id error quis ab aliquam non iste molestiae obcaecati maxime fugiat ut eius incidunt? Veniam.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas possimus ex consectetur ipsam alias, aperiam
            labore doloremque placeat perferendis quisquam numquam at earum dolorem deleniti libero! Magni non explicabo
            aspernatur! Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto similique error animi deleniti porro
            modi aut iste necessitatibus tempore et eligendi dolorum, esse omnis sequi veritatis quas maxime officiis
            incidunt. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, nam aspernatur delectus optio quos
            eveniet repudiandae culpa quo esse corporis similique accusamus cum nobis officia totam doloremque? Laudantium,
            corporis dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis illo, ea possimus, aspernatur
            est, impedit natus dolores ipsam eveniet autem maxime sit accusamus doloremque quo veritatis corporis nemo totam
            cupiditate! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus natus dolor inventore nulla
            voluptate sunt eaque, vero odit perferendis. Dolores eius soluta maxime, perferendis provident sit obcaecati
            asperiores quasi inventore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis aliquam, omnis
            fugiat exercitationem vitae accusantium, aspernatur earum quam blanditiis tempore a delectus sunt id ullam
            praesentium, natus eveniet soluta mollitia. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione,
            veniam libero qui deleniti blanditiis repudiandae autem. Inventore nobis, nemo accusamus sit, cum, praesentium
            perspiciatis excepturi animi earum voluptatum ab laudantium? Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Laudantium libero sunt nihil corrupti quisquam a illum labore similique soluta quia voluptatem repellat
            necessitatibus autem ut quos harum accusamus, earum repudiandae. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur
            adipisicing elit. Expedita sunt veniam sed optio cum sequi, id error quis ab aliquam non iste molestiae obcaecati
            maxime fugiat ut eius incidunt? Veniam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas possimus
            ex consectetur ipsam alias, aperiam labore doloremque placeat perferendis quisquam numquam at earum dolorem
            deleniti libero! Magni non explicabo aspernatur! Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto
            similique error animi deleniti porro modi aut iste necessitatibus tempore et eligendi dolorum, esse omnis sequi
            veritatis quas maxime officiis incidunt. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, nam
            aspernatur delectus optio quos eveniet repudiandae culpa quo esse corporis similique accusamus cum nobis officia
            totam doloremque? Laudantium, corporis dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis
            illo, ea possimus, aspernatur est, impedit natus dolores ipsam eveniet autem maxime sit accusamus doloremque quo
            veritatis corporis nemo totam cupiditate! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus
            natus dolor inventore nulla voluptate sunt eaque, vero odit perferendis. Dolores eius soluta maxime, perferendis
            provident sit obcaecati asperiores quasi inventore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Corporis aliquam, omnis fugiat exercitationem vitae accusantium, aspernatur earum quam blanditiis tempore a
            delectus sunt id ullam praesentium, natus eveniet soluta mollitia. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
            adipisicing elit. Ratione, veniam libero qui deleniti blanditiis repudiandae autem. Inventore nobis, nemo
            accusamus sit, cum, praesentium perspiciatis excepturi animi earum voluptatum ab laudantium? Lorem ipsum, dolor
            sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium libero sunt nihil corrupti quisquam a illum labore similique
            soluta quia voluptatem repellat necessitatibus autem ut quos harum accusamus, earum repudiandae. Lorem ipsum,
            dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sunt veniam sed optio cum sequi, id error quis ab aliquam
            non iste molestiae obcaecati maxime fugiat ut eius incidunt? Veniam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
            adipisicing elit. Voluptas possimus ex consectetur ipsam alias, aperiam labore doloremque placeat perferendis
            quisquam numquam at earum dolorem deleniti libero! Magni non explicabo aspernatur! Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet
            consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto similique error animi deleniti porro modi aut iste necessitatibus tempore et
            eligendi dolorum, esse omnis sequi veritatis quas maxime officiis incidunt.
        </div>
        <footer class="mt-auto text-white-50">
            <p class="mb-0">Copyright - Cratex SMP 2024</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>



Any help is apreciated!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode
